# IOS - Hide icon from springboard

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-privateapi

I'm developing an app for personal use (development certificate) without uploading it to the AppStore.

I want the icon to be automatically hidden from the SpringBoard and to be able to looked up from the search.

I tried using:

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
<array>
<string>hidden</string>
</array>
```

But i couldn't make it work (even when changing the bundleID to com.apple.*)

Anythoughts?

(Was tested both on ios 10 and 11).

Comment: `SBAppTags` no longer works because the Springboard explicitly checks which application is trying to use that feature. For all applications inside `/var/mobile/` it is ignored. The logic on previous iOS versions was flawed and that's why it worked. It's very unlikely there's another way to do that. It's an actual feature reserved for pre-installed applications, Apple doesn't need two ways to do the same thing possibly exposing another security flaw.

Comment: Can I contact you in some way?

Answer (score 0):

In short, without a Jailbreak this is not possible and outside the capabilities of your app.
The reason of this is because Apple doesn't want the user of having apps without him knowing about them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand, yet, isn't there is any way to achieve this by "abusing" some kind of private API? I know it the past it was possible with changing manifest.json -> SBAppTags = Hidden.